# Really simple question about creating non-standard sized byte groups

Tags: java, c, byte

So for a project that space really matters in, I'd like to be able to write to a file a number which takes up THREE bytes. So essentially, an unsigned type where 16,777,215 is the highest possible number.

The number is given as an unsigned int, and I've already checked to ensure it's between 0 and 16,777,215. How do I go beyond that?

Code in Java is preferred, but ANSI C works too. Thanks!

Comment: You can use unions in C. _Without code, so this is not an anwser._

Comment: Wow, you can write a three byte value to a file using unions without any code in C?? I am impressed.

Comment: @Peter maybe I didn't get your joke, but the OP asked about code, and I'm lazy now to write it :)

Comment: @peter +1 very funny! ;)

Comment: @khachik, It was meant to be a joke. I assume you took one small piece of the problem and said that didn't require code. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
int number = 
OutputStream os =
os.write(number >> 16);
os.write(number >> 8);
os.write(number);
```

To read

```
InputStream is = 
int number = ((is.read() & 0xFF) << 16) | ((is.read() & 0xFF) << 8) | (is.read() & 0xFF)
```

However, given the cost of a byte is so trivial, you have to save an awful lot of them to make the added complexity worth it. I only included it here for your information.

```
2 TB of disk space is worth about $100
1 GB is worth about 5 cents
1 MB is worth about 0.005 cents
1 KB is worth about 0.000005 cents.
1 B is worth about 0.000000005 cents.
```

For comparison, at minimum wage, (You may value your time more highly)

```
1 minute of your time, 12 cents. ~2 GB.
1 second, 0.2 cents. ~40 MB.
1 key, 0.2 seconds, 0.04 cents ~8 MB.
1 blink. 0.05 seconds, 0.01 cents ~2 MB.
```

This makes the rather disturbing suggestion that its not worth pressing one key to save less that 8 MB. You might even come to the conclusion that its not worth one simple code change unless it saves 2 GB of disk space. :P

Comment: Well, maybe he's programming electric iron or dishwasher, or just needs to store lots of numbers in a mobile phone :) There're always situations when saving 1 byte at the time is useful.

Comment: Who's to say that he's storing them on disk? Maybe he's storing the data in embedded flash. Or maybe he's concerned about I/O bandwidth. Why pass up the opportunity to use 25% less I/O bandwidth?

Comment: If he wants to make the numbers smaller, he could use stop bit encoding. (A simple compression method) That way the numbers can be just one byte.

Comment: @Gabe, there are times you have to use something like this; when you are interfacing with a library which expects 3 byte values. e.g. RGB (24-bit colour)  which is why I included the solution. However, I wanted to make it clear saving some disk space is not worth it unless you do this a hell of alot. e.g. a billion is a maybe.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, 1 Gb of flash memory costs up to $3, implying 30 KB  costs 0.01 cents (time it takes you to blink at minimum wage) ;)

Comment: Peter: Once you pay for RAID, SAS, racks, power, cooling, backup, offsite replication, and so on, enterprises typically charge $10/GB. Some organizations charge $7/GB *per month* to their own internal customers!

Comment: @Gabe, this is all true, however in this case I suggest you have an organisational issue, rather than a technical one. A developer should consider all solutions to a problem and not just assume they should code their way out of every problem. Even at $1000/GB over ten years, each byte costs 10,000 th of a cent.

Answer (score 0):

In C you could always cast the *int into a *char and then write the 3 least significant bytes. For Big Endian, you skip the first char and write the other three, for little endian, you just write the first three bytes.